# discountasp.net classic asp ipworks

Tags: asp-classic, discountasp, ipworks

I need to be able to retrieve emails from SmarterMail (the email that comes with DiscountASP.net). DiscountASP claims they have the IPWorks suite installed, but when I try to invoke it with:

Set imap = Server.CreateObject("IPWorksASP.IMAP")

or

Set imap = Server.CreateObject("IPWorksASP6.IMAP")

I get a server create object error. Can someone tell me the correct syntax for creating the IMAP object of IPWorks on DiscountASP.net?

Thank you - Robert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They never say they have IP*Works available for asp.classic.

Instead, they say they have *IP*Works! Internet Toolkit **.NET Edition** v8*

To use the software from asp.classic, you need ActiveX/COM Edition of the IP*Works! package.

**Update:** you should be able to develop a COM object in C#/VB.NET, that uses IP*Works .NET Edition to  retrieve the e-mails you want, and use that COM object from your asp.classic web site. [Here's one guide](http://limbioliong.wordpress.com/2011/08/30/creating-a-com-server-using-c/) for C#, don't forget about `[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]` attribute (required for the COM object to be accessible from VBScript/ASP.classic).

Comment: Bummer - they apparently have no means by which a classic asp site can retrieve email.

Comment: As they offer shared hosting, they do not permit clients to install COM objects.